# flutter error in android studio : no jdk found

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

when I run flutter doctor it shows no error , but in android studio it gives the error no jdk setup and then everything becomes red as shown in the screenshot below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3MMC.png

what should i do to remove these errors?

Comment: There is an error in your dart codes?

Comment: no sir, my dart code has no error whatsoever, but in my android manifest.xml file it shows unknown attribute for all the attributes and it cannot detect the MainAcitvity.java class too, which makes me think that maybe there is something wrong with the installation

Comment: it also says that there is no jdk found in the top bar of an activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you sure that your flutter path is set correctly in android studio? Go to settings>Languages&Frameworks>Flutter [here is the print screen of setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8zCE.png) and eventually change path to place where yout sdk is located. Also try to run `flutter upgrade` to check for updates.
If it doesn't work make sure that you have installed android SDK. Again go to settings>System settings>Android SDK and there you should check if your android SDK path is set corectly and see if you have at least one android version checked  [here is how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tacpj.png). I hope it will work. Have fun with flutter!

EDIT: Sorry for misleading I didn't read correctly. Steps above are for SDK error. For JDK error you should install Java JDK from this website https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html

Comment: for the flutter sdk path, mine is C:\src\flutter , so I guess that I should put the android sdk there, which is C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk or not?

Comment: thanks for the answer

Comment: No, it shouldn't be in the same place. You need to check if path shown in android studio is the same as your real path on your disk for the SDK. DO you have android 11 SDK installed? Also in Android SDK setting click SDK tools and look if you have Android-SDK platform-tools checked

Comment: thanks lava!!! but my android studio works perfectly and flutter gives the error: no jdk setup, so is sdk checking required? also if you know any good libraries for viewing and displaying 3d models in android studio, pls let me know because if there is, I will not need flutter

Comment: Sorry I don't know any, I'm also new in this world. Omg I'm so sorry I misread. So your problem is with JDK not SDK. You should install java oracle JDK from this site https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html Let me now if it works. I'm really sorry for misleading

Comment: no probs lava, i have installed it and already setup but for some reason it doesn't recognize it, i think that's what giving the error

Comment: Did you set your environment variables for java? Scroll down to Setting the PATH Environment Variable and do following steps. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/install/installation-jdk-and-jre-microsoft-windows-platforms.htm#JSJIG-GUID-E3C75F92-D3B2-421D-A9BE-933C15F7CD1B  Also go to file>project structure>Platfrom settings>SDKs and check if your JDK path is set corectly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230356/discussion-between-android-and-lava).

Comment: yep all that is done, cause my android studio is working normally, I  think I should reinstall flutter